# store a sql report in a sqlce text field?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, sql-server-ce

OK, the above may seem somewhat strange but please bear with me...

I'm building a reporting app. in C# on .NET3.5 which contains a SQLCE 3.5 sp1 database.
I want to use the database to store the sql for the various reports which will be available to users (so they don't have to know anything about the dirty bits..).

When they wish to run a report they just select the appropriate button on the UI and it goes away and picks up the relevant sql from the database and inserts it into a piece of code to run the report, subsequently presenting them with the returned data.

I've got a table structured like so -

- ReportIdx numeric,
- ReportName varchar(120),
- SQL_Txt varchar(MAX),
- Comments varchar(120)

Running the following -

> INSERT INTO
>   SqlLib
>                         (ReportIdx, ReportName, SQL_Txt, Comments)
>   VALUES     (3, 'TestRowInsert02', 'select * from test_table where testid in('1', '2','3') ', 'Wonder IF this will work?')<

I get the following error message -

*Error in values list in INSERT INTO clause.
Unable to parse query text.
Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
Error Message: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3, Token Line offset = 90, Token in error = 1]*

I've tried inserting a forward slash(\) in front of the commas inside the sql_txt value but the above error presents again and the sql insert statement is altered as follows -

> INSERT INTO
>    SqlLib
>                         (ReportIdx, ReportName, SQL_Txt, Comments)
>   VALUES     (3, 'TestRowInsert02', 'select * from test_table where testid in(\' 1 \ ', \' 2 \ ',\' 3 \ ') ', 'Wonder IF this will work?')<

I guess what I really need to know is 'Can I store the sql for a report in a SQLCE Column so it can be simply retrieved and run subsequently in another piece of code?
Can I format the contents so they do not require further processing before I can use it in a SQL report?

Comment: Edit - the forward (escape) slashes in the second example are actually all doubled up by the SQLCE Query parser...

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/02/11/stored-procedures-and-sql-server-compact-the-great-debate.aspx) for ideas on using abstraction in SQLCE .  (a way to encapsulate a set of SQL statements to isolate the underlying store from the programming model)